# jQuery get the id from the parent selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code and this is getting the id attribute of the 'a' element.  However, I'd like to get the id attribute of the original '.panel' class.

Any ideas how to do this?  Thank you!

jQuery:

```
$('.panel .panel_content a').click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Markup:

```
<div class="panel" id="step_2">
     <h3>Title</h3>
        <div class="panel_content">
          <a href="#">Item</a>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('.panel .panel_content a').click(function(){
    alert($(this).closest(".panel").attr('id'));
});
```

Comment: How does this compare to parents?

Comment: @dave, `closest()` includes `this` (the currently matched element) in its search. `parents()` doesn't. Igor mentions another important difference below.

Comment: `closest` will get first parent element of `panel` class, while `parents` will get ALL parents with such class

Comment: the jquery api site (http://api.jquery.com/closest/) lists that the closest begins at the current element rather than the parent. The parents method adds each ancestor to a collections object and filters it based upon the selector given. The closest will stop at the first matching ancestor. So closes is actually more efficient than parents.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.panel .panel_content a').click(function(){
    alert($(this).parents(".panel").attr('id'));
});
```